# Match a content with regexp in a file?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to see if a text already is in a file using regexp.

```
# file.txt
Hi my name is Foo
and I live in Bar
and I have three children.
```

I want to see if the text:

```
Hi my name is Foo
and I live in Bar
```

is in this file.

How can I match it with a regexp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
/Hi my name is Foo
and I live in Bar/
```

Example usage:

```
File.open('file.txt').read() =~ /Hi my name is Foo
and I live in Bar/
```

For something so simple a string search would also work.

```
File.open('file.txt').read().index('Hi my name...')
```

Comment: I believe `File.read('file.txt') =~ ...` would also work and not leave a handle open.

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to support variables instead of "Foo" and "Bar", use:

```
/Hi my name is (\w+)\s*and I live in (\w+)/
```

As seen on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/2yZxeqGRRf).

This also puts "Foo" and "Bar" (or whatever the string contained) in capture groups that you can later use.

```
str = IO.read('file1.txt')    
match = str.match(/Hi my name is (\w+)\s*and I live in (\w+)/)

puts match[1] + ' lives in ' + match[2]
```

Will print:

> > Foo lives in Bar

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use a regexp for checking for a literal string?  Why not just

```
File.open('file.text').read().include? "Hi my name is Foo\nand I live in Bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer with automatic file closing. Can be used to get the first matching regex in the file:

```
found = File.read('file.txt')[/Hi my name is Foo\nand I live in Bar/]
```